# laravel how to validate from custom request object?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate a request like this.

```
public function reply(CustomRequest $request) 
{
    $request->validated();
}
```

The issue is that it will automatically redirect to the previous page if the validation fails. Whereas I want to do some custom logic.

For example

```
if($request->validation->fails()) {
  // Do things
}
```

But I can't find a way to do this without passing in validation rules, whereas I want to use the rules from the "CustomRequest" class.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Validator::make()`, you can redirect your customised stuff.

Here is an example how you can return the first error in the ErrorBag:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'field' => ['required']
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('custom_error', $validator->errors()->first());
};
```

Comment: is it possible to create form request validation using  php artisan make:request name command, and use it in controller inside Validator method ??

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution # 1

```php
public function store (CategoryRequest $request)
{
  if (!$request->validated()) {
    return redirect()->route('categories.create');
  }
  return 'data is validated';
}
```

You can check if the data is not validated by using `validated()` method. If the data is not validated it will return `false`, after it you can put your logic inside the execution block.

#### Solution # 2

Or can use `validator()` helper (instead of `Validator::make()`) with it's `fails()` function.

```php
public function store (CategoryRequest $request)
{
  $validator = $request->validator();
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is using form requests, which means validation is already complete by the time the code reaches the controller.  If the validation failed, the code you've shown will never even run.